# Javascript nested function "not a function"

Tags: javascript

So, I have a javascript file I'm including in my page. Here's the gist of it:

```
var PageTransitions = (function() {

    function setCurrent(currentSet) {
        alert(currentSet);
    }

    function nextPage(options, direction, gotopage) {
        //some working code, not important
    }

})();
```

On the page, I'm using:

```
PageTransitions.nextPage(x, x, x);
```

That works fine. However, trying to use

```
PageTransitions.setCurrent(x);
```

gives me PageTransitions.setCurrent is not a function

Not sure why this is happening, pretty sure the syntax is correct. Unfortunately it's something for work, not allowed to share the actual page where it's occurring. Had our senior dev take a look, but they said it looked like it should be working. Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

I'm calling setCurrent after the javascript file gets called, also tried moving it after nextPage to be sure. nextPage still worked, setCurrent still not a function.

Also tried renaming setCurrent, and the variable it's being passed. Still no good.

Comment: There's something else that sets the variable's value. Neither function is accessible from outside the IIFE in the code you've shown.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a simple IIFE with the module pattern for which you'll need an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to chain, you'll need properties, not just functions defined inside another function, the simplest is an object literal

```
var PageTransitions = {
    setCurrent : function(currentSet) {
        alert(currentSet);
        return this;
    },
    nextPage : function(options, direction, gotopage) {
        //some working code, not important
        return this;
    }
}

PageTransitions.nextPage(x, x, x);
```

or if the IIFE has a purpose, returning an object literal

```
var PageTransitions = (function() {
    function setCurrent(currentSet) { ... }
    function nextPage(options, direction, gotopage) { ... }

    return {setCurrent, nextPage};
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

If `PageTransitions.nextPage(x, x, x);` is working, it's not due to the code you've sent.

You need to return the functions so `PageTransitions` has access to it:

```
var PageTransitions = (function() {

    function setCurrent(currentSet) {
        alert(currentSet);
    }

    function nextPage(options, direction, gotopage) {
        //some working code, not important
    }

    return {
        setCurrent: setCurrent,
        nextPage: nextPage
    };
})();
```

**Now** `PageTransitions.setCurrent` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {

    function setCurrent(currentSet) {
        alert(currentSet);
    }

    function nextPage(options, direction, gotopage) {
        //some working code, not important
    }

    var o = {};  // Dummy object

    // set properties to local functions
    o.setCurrent = setCurrent; 
    o.nextPage = nextPage;

    // Attach dummy to global namespace to make it available
    window.PageTransitions= o;

})();

// Now, you can access your functions via your namespace:
PageTransitions.setCurrent("test");
PageTransitions.nextPage();
```

Comment: Why use the `window.PageTransitions` antipattern when `var PageTransitions` works just fine?

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say that `var PageTransitions` doesn't work. I think that my answer is more clear. Also, that `var` approach is susceptible to hoisting, where my solution isn't.

Comment: @Bergi Also, curious why you call my approach an anti-pattern when the `var approach` results in the same outcome. Both approaches can be adapted to avoid Global, however.

Comment: The problem with `window.` is that it only works in browsers, no other environments. And assigning from inside the IIFE is harder to understand than the revealing module pattern. Btw, what's the problem with hoisting?

Comment: @Bergi I think that my example is simple enough to understand and is a variant of the revealing module pattern. The problem with hoisting here is that only the variable will be hoisted, not the assignment. If you were to attempt to use `PageTransitions` prior to the assignment, you would get an error.